# How do I get multi-output data with label binarization?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to do linear regression and I am encountering an error when pre-processing

Here's the code:

```
def process_attributes(df,train,test):
  continuous=["Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4"]
  cs=MinMaxScaler()
  trainContinuous=cs.fit_transform(train[continuous])
  testContinuous = cs.transform(test[continuous])
  categorical=["Var5","Var6","Var7"]
  CategoricalBinarizer=LabelBinarizer().fit(df[categorical])
  trainCategorical = CategoricalBinarizer.transform(train[categorical])
  testCategorical = CategoricalBinarizer.transform(test[categorical])

  trainX = np.hstack([trainCategorical, trainContinuous])
  testX = np.hstack([testCategorical,testContinuous])

  return (trainX,testX)
```

When I run this:

```
(trainX,testX)=process_attributes(df,train,test)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Multioutput target data is not supported with label binarization

Comment: could you identify the line on which you are getting this error? also, could you tell us about arguments df, train, and test? what are the values in ["Var5","Var6","Var7"]?

Comment: Have you tried fit_transform(df[categorical]) instead of fit(df[categorical])?
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html